# Powershell script : Set-ADUser update email attribute samaccountname variable

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm in need of a Powershell script that will edit all users email attribute within a specific OU in Active Directory.

The code below searches for the correct OU and edits the users email attributes within, however the users email attributes are being replaced with @domain.com instead of samaccountname@domain.com.

Is my syntax wrong: $($_.samaccountname)?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=People,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com" | Set-ADUser -email "$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com"
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not your syntax,  but that the variable `$_` doesn't exist in this context.

To use it you need to be inside a foreach loop.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=People,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com" |
    Foreach-Object { Set-ADUser -email "$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-ADUser -email "$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com"
```

It's quite simpler than that. Just use

```
Set-ADUser -email ($_.samaccountname + "@domain.com")
```